# Check if Web page was already downloaded

Tags: java, html, performance, mongodb, hash

**Context**

I have written a Java crawler which downloads periodically pages listed on Google and containing a set of keywords. These pages are either static (i.e., whose content does not change) or dynamic (i.e., whose content changes since it is user-generated or meant to be updated daily/ecc...). The crawler stores each page in a MongoDB database, saving:

- title
- URL
- content (i.e., HTML content of the whole page)

**The problem**

However, pages may be downloaded multiple times, and it is my objective to understand if a page is already present in my database and prevent the crawler to download it a second time.

**My solution**

Thus, I am hashing the content of the page using the following hash function:

```
private long hashFunction(String text) {
    long h = 1125899906842597L;
    int len = text.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        h = 31*h + text.charAt(i);

    return h;
}
```

and storing the hash value in the database, together with the previously listed fields. Consequently, every time a page is downloaded, I hash its content, and if the hash value is already contained in the database, I discard the page.

**Why my solution does NOT work**

Unfortunately, pages may change a little bit, still proposing the same content all in all. As an example:

- pages downloaded from Twitter change an "authentication token" at each request

Thus, I have a lot of duplicates in my database, which report the same content, and differ just on some characters.

**The question**

Is there any smarter way of tracking differences between pages, so that if changes are minimal, I can recognize that the page is already in the database? Obviously, the solution should have high performance, since the database could become really large and performing exact matches with large documents could be expensive.

**[EDIT] A tentative solution (which could have sense...)**

I thought about:

- extracting only the body from the page
- deleting the tags (i.e., everything in the form <...>)
- computing the hash of the portion of text surviving this operation

Could it have sense?

Comment: Probably not a brilliant solution, but what if you generate the hash from the BODY part of the HTML file only?

Comment: I have already thought about it, but often it changes in little parts (e.g., redirect links, auth...), so this does not solve the problem, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is  checking if a specific version of a page is already present in your database to prevent the crawler from downloading it then the hashing is not the way to go because you would have to download the page anyways to generate the hash.

If you store the [Last-Modified http header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) value, you could use it in all subsequent requests using [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25) http header.
If you follow this way you would have to store

- URL
- Content
- Modified-Date

Storing content is fine for futher processing, however i would advice to use html scraping library that would do it for you. See this question [options-for-html-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

Futhermore i believe that it would be good just not to download data too often (probably this will depend on you problem-domain) but you could simply assume that this page has not change in the last 20 minutes or so. If the page changes very frequently you will be behind the latest version anyways.

Comment: I already thought about using that header. However, when I try to retrieve it from the response, it is not available (it returns null), and I am left with the problem...

Comment: you probably won't find single strategy that will handle most cases. Another one that you could apply is to check if there is an etag header. If it is, store it and use it in subsequent requests to perform conditional requests. Treat generating hash of a page as last resort - also check if simply putting the content into the database won't be quicker than hashing. But most importantly, don't download pages too often. (you can apply some heuristic function to the url - i.e. assume that url with blog in it will not change more often than every day)